# How to boot up two VirtualBox VMs with the same DVD ISO file?

Tags: virtualbox

The path */Users/runner/work/fedora-coreos-vm/fedora-coreos-vm/next_just_a_test* is a DVD ISO file. I would like to use it to boot up two VMs with VirtualBox.

How can I do it in an efficient way? (Preferably minimizing RAM memory and disk usage).
I get an error message:

```
/usr/bin/sudo vboxmanage storagectl firstguest --name IDE Controller --add ide
/usr/bin/sudo vboxmanage storagectl secondguest --name IDE Controller --add ide
/usr/bin/sudo vboxmanage storageattach firstguest --storagectl IDE Controller --port 0 --device 0 --type dvddrive --mtype readonly --medium next_just_a_test
/usr/bin/sudo vboxmanage storageattach secondguest --storagectl IDE Controller --port 0 --device 0 --type dvddrive --mtype readonly --medium next_just_a_test
VBoxManage: error: Cannot register the DVD image '/Users/runner/work/fedora-coreos-vm/fedora-coreos-vm/next_just_a_test' {c93832a7-5b60-4ae5-99f3-ab799194d1ee} because a CD/DVD image '/Users/runner/work/fedora-coreos-vm/fedora-coreos-vm/next_just_a_test' with UUID {dd91eb2b-b2ea-4729-99ad-11204a39c6da} already exists
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 191 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Invalid UUID or filename "next_just_a_test"
```

Additional information: The host computer is running macOS 10.15.

Comment: Maybe with a symbolic link so it would look like 2 different files. Also, what happens it you try those steps on the VirtualBox GUI instead of commands?

Comment: I am writing a GitHub Action so I will need to write it as a script and have no access to any GUI. For all the details: https://github.com/eriksjolund/fedora-coreos-vm/runs/3106557218?check_suite_focus=true (I changed the order of two lines in the output in the question but I think it shouldn't matter).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, adding a symlink could be worth a test. I will try that. The man pages also speak about UUIDs vs file paths. I don't know if the same UUID could be shared somehow between the VMs. The [GitHub Runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners) has limited resources so I would like to find the most resource-efficient solution.

Comment: It seems the example I provided in the question sometimes works. It seems it is undeterministic. The order of the `vboxmanage` commands might be in different orders in my case. The  `vboxmanage` commands are in order for the same VM though. I'm a bit confused as what is happening. Anyway, I tried a new approach where only the first `/usr/bin/sudo vboxmanage storageattach ...` use the filepath. The second time I use the _uuid_ that can be parsed out from the command `/usr/bin/sudo vboxmanage list dvds`. It never failed after that. (I've only tried 3 times so far so it might be luck)

Comment: I haven't tried the symlink approach yet. I'm holding my thumb the uuid-parsing (from `sudo vboxmanage list dvds`) is the way to go.